# Does phaserjs support 3d at all

Tags: mobile, webgl, phaser-framework

I would like to know if it phaser.io supports 3d even a little. I have no plans to build a 3d game but would like my main character to have 3d animations...like flip.

Or even better make orthographic game which is more to my taste.

I have tried google search and have found no indication of that it supports 3d. But pixijs, what it's based on does use webgl.

At least even if 2d can i make it 2d.5 or something

Comment: Phaser/Pixi are pretty much 2D only. They use WebGL for fast graphics performance. You might be able to do an ortho game with Phaser and suggest some "3D" effects with tricks like parallax scrolling, shadows, pre-rendered sprite animations, draw order, etc. Check the forums on html5gamedevs.com, it's a community with mostly Phaser/Pixi devs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, phaser is almost strictly a 2D game engine. Sorry.

If you do plan to make a 3D game I would suggest bablyon.js (http://www.babylonjs.com/) which obviously is slightly more complex than phaser but still supports 3D.

Answer (score 2):

No, both Phaser 2 and Phaser 3 do not include any "real" 3d elements and there are no signs that they will be added soon or ever.

However, the creator of Phaser published the Phaser 3D class in the [April 2019 Phaser Backer Examples](https://phaser.io/news/2019/04/phaser-backer-examples-april) (for patreons only) which allows to easily integrate some 3d elements from three.js.

There is also an example how to integrate three.js inside Phaser 3 in the [official Phaser 3 examples](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cbugs%5Cextern.js).

*In the past few weeks I have developed a 3D objects and physics extension for Phaser 3. You will find it at [enable3d.io](https://enable3d.io/).*

Comment: If you promote a product or service and are affiliated with it you need to disclose it.

Comment: also this is more of a comment not an answer

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent BabylonJS framework, here is a curated list of awesome game development tools, platforms, frameworks, engines on GitHub https://github.com/ellisonleao/magictools

PhaserJS-3 does have a [3D camera / perspective camera](http://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=camera/3D%20camera/&q=) too.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody, looking there is "now" an option with an plugin, here an article highlighting this fact: https://phaser.io/news/2020/04/enable3d.

Of course since the plugin can be used standalone, **phaser** is not really needed. Here the link to the project page: https://enable3d.io/.
I haven't tried it yet, but since it is the most promising option, I will have to testdrive it soon.